How many times did Isaac Newton repeat things if he didn't understand something?
When I was taking a class in university, I heard the professor say that if there was a part of Isaac Newton that he didn't understand, he had to read it over and over again hundreds of times. Is this story true? If so, what is the source of that story?
And I read a book about the life of Isaac Newton to find out this story for myself, and I saw an article by John Conduitt saying that Newton repeatedly read Descartes' book. I think this may be an exaggerated explanation, but in conclusion, I am curious about the source and how many times Isaac Newton repeated the story if he did not understand it.
text by John Conduitt

He then young as he was took in hand DesCartes's Geometry (that book which Descartes in his Epistles with a sort of defiance says is so difficult to understand) he began with the most crabbed studies & books (like a high spirited horse who must be first broke in plowed grounds & the roughest & steepest ways or could otherwise be kept within no bounds When he had read two or three pages could understand no farther he being too reserved or modest to trouble any person to instruct him began again & got over three or four more till he came to another difficult place, & then began again & advanced farther & continued so doing till he not only made himself master of the whole without having the least light or instruction from any body but discovered the errors of Descartes, as appears by the original book which he read at that time & is still in being & marked in many places in his own hand writing with these words Error


in my humble opinion possibly you misunderstood your professor.  I get the impression that if there was part of Isaac Newton's writings the professor didn't understand, he reread Newton over and over again.   I don't' get the imprssion that the professsor said that Newton would read anything he didn't understand over and over again.  If the professor wass talking about Newton's learning process and not about his understanding of Newton, you  reported his words poorly.

William Whewell, History of the Inductive Sciences, 3rd ed., Vol. 1, New York: D. Appleton and Company 1858, p. 392: "Voltaire has observed, far more truly, that Newton's edifice rested on no stone of Descartes' foundations. He illustrates this by relating that Newton only once read the work of Descartes, and, in doing so, wrote
the word "error," repeatedly, on the first seven or eight pages; after which he read no more. This volume, Voltaire adds, was for some time in the possession of Newton's nephew." I can't assess the veracity of this story, but it contradicts the one in the question

Conduitt's notes are based on personal conversations with Newton in 1726 and so have some credibility. Westfall's biography of Newton, Never at Rest, pp. 98-99, quotes Conduitt's passage and compares it to de Moivre's from his 1727 conversation with Newton. De Moivre wrote that Newton "read all of Euclid twice". Westfall does not find the latter likely because Pemberton reported Newton's regret over not studying enough Euclid before getting to Descartes. But Conduitt and de Moivre agree on reading of Descartes, and Newton gave a similar account of his studies to Abbe Conti in 1715-16.
